# Search Result Customization

Tags: google-search-appliance

Currently we have to two connectors in our GSA. Our search results have three tabs: All, Connector1, Connector2 .

All includes both connector1 and connector2 results. Is it possible to configure so that Connector2 results appear only in Connector2 tab, and not in All results?

I would appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to exclude the connector 2 results from the collection that you're using for the 'All' tab (assuming you're using collections for this). 
This question is very similar to what you are asking: [Search in default_collection minus a specific collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754092/search-in-default-collection-minus-a-specific-collection/28798533#28798533)

Comment: Thank you,  the post was very informative  . I will try out the steps that you mentioned in the link, and confirm if helped me solve the problem.